# Can't connect to MySQL server at 127.0.0.1 using c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, c3p0

Trying to connect to MySQL server using the following code in Java with c3p0:

```
comboPooledDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();  
comboPooledDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/" + Dbname);  
comboPooledDataSource.setUser(Username);  
comboPooledDataSource.setPassword(Password);  
comboPooledDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(15);  
comboPooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(20);  
comboPooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(10);  
connection = comboPooledDataSource.getConnection();
```

Although I have checked that the DB is up and running and I can connect to it using Python it keeps throwing me the following error:

```
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool...com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource@b4c966a[ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> b4c966a, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> -1, initialPoolSize -> 30, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:jtds:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sip_base, loginTimeout -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 10, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 300, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
Μαϊ 12, 2015 10:41:12 ΠΜ com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@7e2889c7 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30).
Μαϊ 12, 2015 10:41:12 ΠΜ com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@372567de -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30).
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:104)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:264)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(PoolBackedDataSource.java:94)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.getConnection(ComboPooledDataSource.java:521)
at gov.nist.sip.proxy.extended.DBServer.<init>(DBServer.java:52)
at gov.nist.sip.proxy.extended.DBServer.getInstance(DBServer.java:64)
at gov.nist.sip.proxy.extended.DBServer.main(DBServer.java:161)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:972)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:208)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:260)
... 5 more
```

Comment: Try dropping your initial pool size - `comboPooledDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(2);`. At least make it less than your `maxPoolSize`.

Comment: Does `connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/" + Dbname, Username, Password);` work? If not, neither will the c3p0 code above. Please check that. Also look in your logs for an earlier Exception describing the failure of the last attempt to acquire a Connection from the DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. It turned out that I didn't have a jdbc server installed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to set your initial pool size to more than your max pool size - this is unlikely to work.

```
comboPooledDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(30);  // <<-- Reduce this 
comboPooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(20);  // <<-- to something less than this.
```